# Didn't find class "adaptive-icon" on path: DexPathList after adding adaptive icons

Tags: android

Like the title says, I get that error after switching to adaptive icons and trying to load R.ic_launcher. What am I doing wrong here? The icons also shows up as the default green android in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that apis lower than 26 don't support the class. To fix, rename the folder with the ic_launcher.xml file to mipmap-anydpi-v26.